# Why is Unity throwing a NullReferenceException when using async/await plugin in Editor Mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await

I am trying to show a simple image on a Unity Editor window, it worked for a while and then I guess I made some changes that broke it and I keep getting a NullReferenceException. Here is my simple example:

```
public class ShowImagePreview : EditorWindow
{
  private Texture2D texture;

  private async Task<Texture2D> GetHTTPTextureAsync(string imageUrl)
  {
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(imageUrl);
    await request.SendWebRequest();

    if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
    {
      Debug.Log("Something went wrong!");
      Debug.Log(request.error);
      return null;
    }

    return ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
  }

  private async Task OnGUI()
  {
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal("box");
    if (texture != null)
    {
      GUILayout.Label("Texture is not null!");
      GUILayout.Box(texture, GUILayout.Width(140), GUILayout.Height(100));
    }
    else
    {
      GUILayout.Label("Texture is NULL!");
      try
      {
        // This is what's causing the issue and keeping the texture value to null
        texture = await GetHTTPTextureAsync("https://nikkorpon.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/random-shots-059.jpg");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Debug.Log(e);
      }
    }
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
  }
}
```

This is an extract from a larger script. The image urls are actually dynamic but for the sake of this example I just grabbed a random image url. I am using the Async/Await plugin which works as expected with any other request. Any idea about what I might be doing wrong ?

Here is the error message in full:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at IEnumeratorAwaitExtensions.RunOnUnityScheduler (System.Action action) [0x00042] in /Users/user_name/Projects/project_name/Assets/Plugins/AsyncAwaitUtil/Source/IEnumeratorAwaitExtensions.cs:128 
  at IEnumeratorAwaitExtensions.GetAwaiterReturnSelf[T] (T instruction) [0x00025] in /Users/user_name/Projects/project_name/Assets/Plugins/AsyncAwaitUtil/Source/IEnumeratorAwaitExtensions.cs:115 
  at IEnumeratorAwaitExtensions.GetAwaiter (UnityEngine.AsyncOperation instruction) [0x00002] in /Users/user_name/Projects/project_name/Assets/Plugins/AsyncAwaitUtil/Source/IEnumeratorAwaitExtensions.cs:55 
  at ShowImagePreview+<GetHTTPTextureAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00033] in /Users/user_name/Projects/project_name/Assets/Resources/Scripts/Import.cs:18 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <f2e6809acb14476a81f399aeb800f8f2>:0 
  at ShowImagePreview+<OnGUI>c__async1.MoveNext () [0x0010b] in /Users/user_name/Projects/project_name/Assets/Resources/Scripts/Import.cs:43 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<OnGUI>c__async1:MoveNext() (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/Import.cs:47)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder:Start(<OnGUI>c__async1&)
ShowImagePreview:OnGUI()
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Can you include the error message, and add a note to your code where it is erroring?

Comment: Absolutely, sorry I forgot to add that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @DourHighArch I already checked that and could not find something that would help solve my problem. You can see in my code that I have an explicit null check on the texture. I will dig again in that post to double check I didn't miss anything. Also there are no reference at all to the use of async/await and how that could lead to a NullReferenceError. If there's a solution to this problem in that post please would you mind pointing me in the right direction ?

Comment: It looks like an issue in `IEnumeratorAwaitExtensions`. Checking the source code (I'm assuming https://github.com/modesttree/Unity3dAsyncAwaitUtil/blob/master/UnityProject/Assets/Plugins/AsyncAwaitUtil/Source/IEnumeratorAwaitExtensions.cs), the only thing that could be null is `SyncContextUtil.UnitySynchronizationContext`. This would happen if the `SyncContextUtil.Install` method isn't run: https://github.com/modesttree/Unity3dAsyncAwaitUtil/blob/master/UnityProject/Assets/Plugins/AsyncAwaitUtil/Source/Internal/SyncContextUtil.cs

Comment: Unfortunately I know almost nothing about Unity, so I don't know how the `RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod` attribute works and in what conditions Unity is supposed to invoke the decorated method. That said, you can start by validating my hypothesis by checking whether `SyncContextUtil.UnitySynchronizationContext` is null before calling `await request.SendWebRequest()`

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I was hoping it was something silly I was doing wrong. I'll dig a bit deeper and try to trace back the source of the exception.

Comment: Yeah the SyncContextUtil.UnitySynchronizationContext is null and it's trying to invoke a .Post method on it but since that's null it throws that error.

Comment: So either `SyncContextUtil.Install` isn't invoked by Unity, or `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null when it does. What is the value of `SyncContextUtil.UnityThreadId`? If it's equal to 0 then `SyncContextUtil.Install` isn't invoked. If it's equal to any other value then `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null.

Comment: Found the culprit! So Unity calls the "RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod" only in Play mode which calls the "Install". Since I am using this in Editor mode that call is not triggered, they suggested a fix for it in one of the issues in the repo (https://github.com/modesttree/Unity3dAsyncAwaitUtil/issues/9). So I must have activate Play mode for a second which triggered the Install method, then stopped it but from then on it would work.

Comment: I then completely closed Unity and reopened it, without ever using play mode the Install method was never triggered and nothing would work even though I did not change anything in my code. So that explains this odd behavior.

Comment: Well played! Now you can summarize that in an answer for future generations :)

Comment: Exactly, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the culprit!

The code per se works just fine and there are no errors with it. The main issue (thanks to some digging by @KevinGosse) is triggered by the Async/Await plugin code.

Once I put a debugger at line 128 of [IEnumeratorAwaitExtensions.cs](https://github.com/modesttree/Unity3dAsyncAwaitUtil/blob/master/UnityProject/Assets/Plugins/AsyncAwaitUtil/Source/IEnumeratorAwaitExtensions.cs) I noticed that `SyncContextUtil.UnitySynchronizationContext` was null and that's what was causing the `NullReference` error.

The `SyncContextUtil.UnitySynchronizationContext` is initilized in the [SyncContextUtil.cs](https://github.com/modesttree/Unity3dAsyncAwaitUtil/blob/master/UnityProject/Assets/Plugins/AsyncAwaitUtil/Source/Internal/SyncContextUtil.cs) script file thanks to the `Install` method. So the question was, why isn't this method triggered ?

Looking at the source you can see the decorator `[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]` which simply invokes the `Install` method when **Play Mode** is triggered! But I am working in **Editor Mode** so the `Install` method is not triggered and `SyncContextUtil.UnitySynchronizationContext` remains `null` no matter what I do.

Turns out this issue is know in the repo and you can check it out [here](https://github.com/modesttree/Unity3dAsyncAwaitUtil/issues/9). They propose a solution to this exact issue to allow the use of Async/Await in Editor Mode.

For me it was very puzzling why it worked at some point and then it wasn't without me making any code change. The reason was that I activated the Play Mode for a second, then stopped it and continued working in Editor Mode. As we mentioned before starting the Play Mode would call the `Install` method which is what makes everything work properly. I then closed Unity, restarted it and (without ever activating Play Mode) none of my scripts were working anymore!

I will now follow the approach suggested in the issue comment to make Async/Await work as expected in Editor Mode as well. I hope this answer will help others as well!

**EDIT**

I added a decorator to the `Install` method and I don't have the error anymore. Here is the modified code:

```
namespace UnityAsyncAwaitUtil
{
    public static class SyncContextUtil
    {
        [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]
        [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
        static void Install()
        {
            // As suggested by @derHugo you can add a null check here
            // which will prevent initializing these parameters twice
            // see his comment for more info
            if (UnitySynchronizationContext == null) {
              UnitySynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            }
            if (UnityThreadId == null) {
              UnityThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            }
        }

        public static int UnityThreadId
        {
            get; private set;
        }

        public static SynchronizationContext UnitySynchronizationContext
        {
            get; private set;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested this for use of Async/Await in Editor Mode so please run your own tests to make sure this change works for your case as well.

Comment: You might want to remove the `RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)` or add a check. I'm not sure how these are handled when multiple attributes are used but I would guess it might get called twice on runtime (only in editor though) now since `InitializeOnLoadMethod` is also called when entering play mode

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, it got my Editor code working. However it also creates a gameObject called "AsyncCoroutineRunner" for every time I call my code. Did this happen to you to and if so, how'd you manage this?